# Select, where JSON Array contains

Tags: php, mysql, json, laravel, eloquent

So in Laravel 5 there's the handy thing called *JSON Where Clauses* using MySQL's new ability to store and fetch JSON stored in a column:

```
User::where('meta->colors', 'red')->get()
```

would return all rows, where `colors` in the column `meta` would be set to `red`.

Now let's say `colors` is not a string, but an array containing multiple colors (`colors => ['red', 'blue', 'green']`).

What would be an efficient way to retrieve all rows, where `colors` contains e.g. the value `red`?

Comment: Did you mean $x = ['red', 'blue', 'green']; or $x = (colors => ['red', 'blue', 'green']) ?

Comment: Have you tried WhereIn condition ???

Comment: To clarify: The user has a property / column, lets say it's called `meta`, which contains the following JSON:
```{
  "colors": ["red", "blue", "green"]
}```

And I want to retrieve it, if `colors` contains the value `red`.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[`JSON_CONTAINS()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-contains) does exactly what you're looking for:

> **`JSON_CONTAINS(target, candidate[, path])`**
>
> *Indicates by returning 1 or 0 whether a given candidate JSON document is contained within a target JSON document, or—if a path argument was supplied—whether the candidate is found at a specific path within the target. — [12.16.3 Functions That Search JSON Values](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-contains)*

Currently, Laravel's query builder does not provide a corresponding API. There's an [open internals proposal](https://github.com/laravel/internals/issues/296) for it though.

In the meantime, you can execute a raw query:

```php
\DB::table('users')->whereRaw(
    'JSON_CONTAINS(meta->"$.colors", \'["red"]\')'
)->get();
```

Which would return all users that have "red" in their `meta->colors` JSON field. Note that the [`->` operator](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html#operator_json-column-path) requires MySQL 5.7.9+.

You can also call the `whereRaw()` directly on an Eloquent model.

#### Laravel 5.6

As of the 5.6 release, Laravel's query builder contains a new [`whereJsonContains`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.6/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php#L1445) method.

Comment: how do you replace this ["red"] with array variable?

Comment: That's already an array, you can add items to it. Look at the `JSON_CONTAINS` documentation for more information on this.

Comment: It looks like Laravel 5.7 will include `whereJsonContains` for MySQL, PostgreSQL, and SQL Server: https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/24330

Comment: `whereJsonContains` was introduced in Laravel 5.6

Comment: @SamuelReid Updated the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

I think a way would be using the `like` operator:

```
User::where('meta->colors', 'like', '%"red"%')
```

However, this would only work if the values never contain the character `"` and the delimiters wouldn't change.

Answer (score 3):

**An update for this answer**, according to [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-contains) or [MariaDb](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/json_contains/), the correct syntax must be `JSON_CONTAINS(@json, 'red', '$.colors')`, and is necessary to use `JSON_EXTRACT`.

#### So them, the code inside Laravel (for version 5.5 or less).

> Like say [@Elwin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46055223/select-where-json-array-contains#comment79070338_46055223), `meta` column must contains the following JSON: `{ "colors": ["red", "blue", "green"] }`

```php
User::whereRaw("JSON_CONTAINS(JSON_EXTRACT(meta, '$.colors'), '\"{$color}\"')")
```

Remember to use double quotes in value sentence.
`JSON_CONTAINS(JSON_EXTRACT(meta, '$.colors'), '"red"')`

Comment: This work perfectly on my Laravel 6.x and mariadb 10.x

Answer (score -3):

The `whereIn` method verifies that a given column's value is contained within the given array.
Try this:

```
$colorArray = ['red', 'blue', 'green'];

$user = User::whereIn($meta->color, $colorArray)->get();
```

More about [**Laravel's whereIn**](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#where-clauses).

Comment: I meant basically the other way around: The user object contains an array, and I want to retrieve it, if the _user_ contains the given value.

Comment: What OP looks for is totally different from what `whereIn` yields. See [why](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46289938/65732).