# How to sum in a json field that contains an array of objects with Eloquent

Tags: laravel, postgresql

```
[
  {"id":4,"sum":19},
  {"id":3,"sum":9},
  {"id":6,"sum":32}, 
  {"id":2,"sum":32}
]
```

I'm trying this, but it finds only by  1 value, how to find by sum of "sum" values?

```
 $query->whereJsonContains('programs', [['sum' => intval($search)]]);
```

Comment: your query has a where clause, so it will find the row where it has the integer you defined, and only that value.

Comment: can you explain more about what you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
//...
->whereRaw(
'JSON_CONTAINS(programs->"$[*].sum", "' . intval($search) . '")')->get();
```

[See related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46055223/select-where-json-array-contains)

Answer (score 3):

This is now supported on eloquent.
This worked for me on Laravel 8 using MySQL 5.7:

```
Entity::sum('json_column->field')
```