# How to store and retrieve nested JSON array in laravel 6

Tags: mysql, json, laravel, laravel-6.2

I am trying to retrieve the data saved as json in mysql. My migration looks like below:

```
Schema::create('items', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name')->nullable();
        $table->json('add_ons')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

I have tried saving the below JSON from postman and it saved perfectly.

```
{
    "itemName": "chicken",
    "addons": {
        "required": false,
        "min": 2,
        "max": 3,
        "data": [
            {
                "name": "sauces",
                "type": [
                    {
                        "name": "white sauce",
                        "type": [
                            {
                                "name": "whiteOne",
                                "price": 10
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "whiteTwo",
                                "price": 20
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "red sauce",
                        "price": 10
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Now, I trying to retrieve the price of '*whiteOne*' under '*white sauce*' and getting nothing other than null or laravel error response.

I have tried

```
Item::whereJsonContains('add_ons->data->name','sauces')->get()
Item::whereJsonContains('add_ons->data->name','sauces')->find(16)
```

After saving the 'add_ons' column has below data:

```
{
  "required": false,
  "min": 2,
  "max": 3,
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "sauces",
      "type": [
        {
          "name": "white sauce",
          "type": [
            {
              "name": "whiteOne",
              "price": 10
            },
            {
              "name": "whiteTwo",
              "price": 20
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "red sauce",
          "price": 10
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: I think it is typo in `add_ons->data` - it has to be `add_ons->addons->data`

Comment: Thanks for rectifying one of the issues.  Tried your suggestion but it is not working.@RobinGillitzer

Comment: What do you get with these: `Item::whereJsonContains('add_ons->itemName','chicken')->get();`

Comment: ````Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#306 ▼
  #items: []
}
````
@RobinGillitzer

Comment: What is your MySQL version?

Comment: ````
Database server

Server: 127.0.0.1 via TCP/IP

Server type: MariaDB

Server connection: SSL is not being used Documentation

Server version: 10.4.6-MariaDB - mariadb.org binary distribution

Protocol version: 10

User: root@localhost

Server charset: cp1252 West European (latin1)

````
````
Web server
Apache/2.4.39 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1c PHP/7.3.8

Database client version: libmysql - mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev - 20150407 - $Id: 7cc7cc96e675f6d72e5cf0f267f48e167c2abb23 $

PHP extension: mysqli curl mbstring

PHP version: 7.3.8

````
@RobinGillitzer

Comment: Can you add an excerpt of you DB entry?

Comment: Please check the link for the screenshot.

https://prnt.sc/r4juy8

Comment: You can also try the `whereRaw` method like mentioned in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46055223/select-where-json-array-contains

Comment: The JSON structure is different from that what you have posted. Please replace the content of your JSON with that from the database. And please try to describe your question better. I think you would like to have something else then you try.

Comment: I have added the json part in the question as after saved part. @RobinGillitzer

Comment: @Debu thank you. Now please try to explain your question better. Try to give examples of your expected results. You only want to list the sauces of one item? You want to get all items that have one sauce? And so on...

Comment: @RobinGillitzer Thanks for helping me out.

I trying to fetch the price of **whiteOne** which is located under  **white sauce** from the array of objects.  Also I am trying to fetch the price of **red sauce** which is a single object.

Suppose I get a POST request with ItemId and addon name as **red sauce** or **white sauce** and in response I need to send the price associated with that addon name. How can i achieve it?

Comment: If the addon name you got from the POST contains `white sauce` what do you expect then? Because there are two different objects in.

Comment: In POST request for **white sauce** I will get 3 parameters **(sauces,white sauce & whiteOne)**. 

For **red sauce** I will get 2 parameters **(sauces & red sauce)**

On the basis of the above I want to retrieve it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208120/discussion-between-robin-gillitzer-and-debu).

Comment: @RobinGillitzer Are you there?

Answer (score 0):

I used this function to get the value of the index.

```
public function search($array, $key, $value) { 
        // RecursiveArrayIterator to traverse an 
        // unknown amount of sub arrays within 
        // the outer array. 
        $arrIt = new \RecursiveArrayIterator($array); 

        // RecursiveIteratorIterator used to iterate 
        // through recursive iterators 
        $it = new \RecursiveIteratorIterator($arrIt); 

        foreach ($it as $sub) { 

            // Current active sub iterator 
            $subArray = $it->getSubIterator(); 

            if ($subArray[$key] === $value) { 
                //$result[] = iterator_to_array($subArray); 
                $result = iterator_to_array($subArray); 
             } 
        } 
        return $result; 
    }
```

Now when I pass the values in the function I get the appropriate values.

```
$item = Item::where('id','=',16)->first();
$res = $this->search($item->add_ons['data'], 'name', 'whiteTwo'); 
echo $res["name"]." - ".$res['price'] ."<br>";
```